# Test Agent build error in VSTS

Tags: c#, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

i want to run coded ui test on my local machine from VSTS build.I have both test controller and test agent installed in my local machine and test agent status is online.But when i build the solution from Deploy test agent in VSTS build,i am getting this error...please help

> System.Exception: Error occured on '127.0.0.1:5985'. Details :
>   'Connecting to remote server 127.0.0.1 failed with the following error
>   message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in
>   the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and
>   is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
>   WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
>   WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
>   command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service:
>   "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'. For troubleshooting, refer
>   https://aka.ms/remotevstest. System.InvalidOperationException: Deploy
>   Test Agent task has failed on all machines. Check the logs for more
>   details. at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DtlMachineDeploymentHelper.ThrowIfNumberOfTargetMachinesAreZero(String
>   exceptionMessage) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DtlMachineDeploymentHelper.CopyBinariesToRemoteMachines(String
>   sourcePath, String destinationPath, Boolean isTestAgentCopy, Boolean
>   fallBackRun) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.TryCopyBinariesFromBAToTestMachines(Boolean
>   fallBackRun) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.TryTestAgentCopyOrDownload(TestAgentToTestMachineDelegate[]
>   testAgentDel) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.CopyAgentToTestMachines()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TaskRunner.Run(Dictionary`2
>   arguments, VssConnection connection, TaskType taskType) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployAndConfigureTestAgentCmdlet.ProcessRecord()

Answer (score 0):

Please configure the test agent by following the steps here: [How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) and then try again.